# How do I ensure the last TreeNode (in a TreeView) is fully visible?

Tags: winforms, treeview

I'm using a TreeView control and adding nodes programatically.  Because I want my last node to always be visible (ie. automatically scroll the treeview) I am calling TreeNode.EnsureVisible() on the last node.

However, if the node is only a tiny, tiny bit visible (ie. just a sliver) it is considered visible.  If I try to scroll the TreeView it still doesn't show me the last node.

How can I make sure my last TreeNode is 100% visible?

Comment: This is not normal, what operating system are you using?  Finding out it isn't fully visible is easy with the TreeNode.Bounds property.  Fixing it is very difficult, you'd have to call EnsureVisible on the next *visible* node.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was looking for the similar problem and I found this page:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814354

The page acknowledges that its a bug and the workaround is calling **BeginUpdate()** and **EndUpdate()** methods:

```
TreeView1.BeginUpdate()    
TreeView1.Nodes.Add("test")    
TreeView1.EndUpdate()
```

Nirmal